# How to fix a UITableView class which repeat twice elements read on Firebase database and in the load the table is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read from firebase realtime database a series of instructions.

I have an unknown number of information on my Vehicles node, so I just use `nextObject` method to get the number of times that the function need to iterate.

The problem is that at the opening, my table is empty. When I click on the searchbar then my cells contents did appear. How can I solve these problem?

Here my `UITableView` file:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Alamofire




class Vehicles: UITableViewController,
UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    //variables
    var model: NSMutableArray = []
    var numberOfVehicles: NSMutableArray = []
    var price: NSMutableArray = []
    var imagePathString: NSMutableArray = []
    var detailpage: NSMutableArray = []



    var populator: NSMutableArray = []
    var searching = false
    var matches = [Int]()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    @IBOutlet weak var InfoTableView: UITableView!

    var InfoList: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
        //this should reload but, it didn't.
        self.InfoTableView.reloadData()
        //then the searchbar that is good and don't have any problem.
        searchingField()
    }



    func loadData() {
        //read data from database
        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
        let conditionalRef = rootRef.child("Vehicles")
        conditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snap: DataSnapshot) in
            // Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
            let snapshotChildren = snap.children
            // Loop over all children in Firebase
            while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                // Get code node key and save it to they array
                self.populator.add(child.key)
                if self.populator.contains("\(child.key)") {
                    let userRef = rootRef.child("Vehicles").child("\(child.key)")

                    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                        let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

                            let model1 = userDict["Model"] as! String
                            self.model.add(model1)

                            let detail1 = userDict["Detail"] as! String
                            self.detailpage.add(detail1)

                            let numberOfVehicles1 = userDict["numberOfVehicles"] as! String
                            self.numberOfVehicles.add(numberOfVehicles1)

                            let Price1 = userDict["Price"]  as! String
                            self.price.add(Price1)

                            let imageURL1 = userDict["imageURL"]  as! String
                            self.imagePathString.add(imageURL1)
                    }) //end second observeSingleEvent

                }
              else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "No one vehicle found", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            } //end searching object in Vehicles node



            } //end first observeSingleEvent

      }//end func


    func searchingField() {
        //setup searchbar
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        ]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Dismiss"
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
    }





    // MARK: Search Controller
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        var regArray = self.model as NSArray as! [String]
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text,
            !searchText.isEmpty { 
            matches.removeAll()

            for index in 0..<model.count {
                if regArray[index].lowercased().contains(
                    searchText.lowercased()) {
                    matches.append(index)
                }
            }
            searching = true
        } else {
            searching = false
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return searching ? matches.count : model.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return searching ? matches.count : model.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "TableCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! Vehicles_cell



        let row = indexPath.row
        var regArray = self.model as NSArray as! [String]
        cell.Label.text = searching ? regArray[matches[row]] : model[row] as! String
        cell.Subtitle?.text = "N. Vehicles: \(self.numberOfVehicles[indexPath.row]) - Price: \(self.price[indexPath.row])$"


        Alamofire.request("\(self.imagePathString[indexPath.row])").response { response in
            guard let image = UIImage(data:response.data!) else {
                // Handle error
                return
            }
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
            cell.Image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cell.Image.image = UIImage(data : imageData!)
        }

        return cell
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowrentDetails" {

            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            //save detail1 in UserDefault
            let SVDetail = self.detailpage[myIndexPath.row]
            let SVDetaildefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            SVDetaildefaults.set(SVDetail, forKey: "sv_detail")
            SVDetaildefaults.synchronize()
            _ = segue.destination
                as! Vehicles_Detail
        }
    }

    //IMPOSTA LE DIMENSIONI DELLE CELLE
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.row {
        default:
            return 100
        }
    }


}
```

I expect the table show on the opening all the data from database, while actually  and not repeat unless I click on the searchbar. And the table shouldn't be repeated twice.

---

**Edit (solution to duplicates)**

This is so embarrassing. The answer to this problem is simple

In `numberOfSections` function, I used address.count instead to use 1 Section. So, what I saw were not duplicate cells, but new block sections of `model.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tableview isn't reloading data once it is fetched during the Firebase observation, but is in `updateSearchResults()`. Does adding `self.InfoTableView.reloadData()` inside your `loadData()` in between the `//end searching object in Vehicles node` and `//end first observeSingleEvent` closing brackets fix the issue?

Edit: The reason your reload of tableview data doesn't fix the issue within `viewDidLoad()` is because it gets called before the `loadData()` function starts to iterate through your Firebase data objects. By doing it at the end of the Firebase observation, you're ensuring that you've loaded all of your data from Firebase prior to calling the reload.

Comment: Hi Kyle, thank you very much, to helped me to reasoning about this problem.
I just tried to put this before //end second observeSingleEvent and it works now, thank you really so much. Now remains only the problem that these data repeat twice, is there a way to solve also this?

Comment: Your snapshot from Firebase doesn't remove all objects from your mutable arrays before observing again so you may be adding duplicates each time this is called. Does adding `array.removeAll()` for each array you have on the lines above `let snapshotChildren = snap.children` work?

Comment: Nope, but if I add this after the observation remains only the last cell. Maybe shall I use a dictionary to avoid duplicates?